# Covering all the cases of a promoted datatype

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

So I recently came up with this neat idea, in the hope of sharing code between the strict and lazy `State` transformer modules:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}
module State where

data Strictness = Strict | Lazy
newtype State (t :: Strictness) s a = State (s -> (s, a))

returnState :: a -> State t s a
returnState x = State $ \s -> (s, x)

instance Monad (State Lazy s) where
  return = returnState
  State ma >>= amb = State $ \s -> case ma s of
    ~(s', x) -> runState (amb x) s'

instance Monad (State Strict s) where
  return = returnState
  State ma >>= amb = State $ \s -> case ma s of
    (s', x) -> runState (amb x) s'

get :: State t s s
get = State $ \s -> (s, s)

put :: s -> State t s ()
put s = State $ \_ -> (s, ())
```

You can see that `get` and `put` both work without any duplication – no type class instances, no anything – on both the strict and lazy types. However, even though I cover both possible cases for `Strictness`, I don't have a Monad instance for `State t s a` in general:

```
-- from http://blog.melding-monads.com/2009/12/30/fun-with-the-lazy-state-monad/
pro :: State t [Bool] ()
pro = do
  pro
  s <- get
  put (True : s)

-- No instance for (Monad (State t [Bool])) arising from a do statement
```

The following works fine, albeit requiring `FlexibleContexts`:

```
pro :: (Monad (State t [Bool])) => State t [Bool] ()
-- otherwise as before
```

Then I can instantiate `t` at `Lazy` or `Strict` and run the result and get what I expect. But why do I have to give that context? Is this a conceptual limitation, or a practical one? Is there some reason I'm missing why `Monad (State t s a)` actually doesn't hold, or is there just no way to convince GHC of it yet?

(Aside: using the context `Monad (State t s)` *doesn't* work:

> `Could not deduce (Monad (State t [Bool])) arising from a do statement`
>   `from the context (Monad (State t s))`

which just confuses me even more. Surely the former is deducible from the latter?)

Comment: It's indeed a limitation of `DataKinds`. I've seen something related happen, where GHC couldn't figure out that the patterns of a GADT with `DataKinds` were exhaustive, and it generated suggestions that wouldn't type-check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a limitation, but one with good reason: if it did not work that way what would the expected semantics of

```
runState :: State t s a -> s -> (s,a)
runState (State f) s = f s

example :: s -> a
example = snd $ runState ((State undefined) >> return 1) ()
```

well, it could be

```
example = snd $ runState ((State undefined) >>= \_ -> return 1) ()
        = snd $ runState (State $ \s -> case undefined s of (s',_) -> (s',1)) ()
        = snd $ case undefined () of (s',_) -> (s',1)
        = snd $ case undefined of (s',_) -> (s',1)
        = snd undefined
        = undefined
```

or it could be

```
example = snd $ runState ((State undefined) >>= \_ -> return 1) ()
        = snd $ runState (State $ \s -> case undefined s of ~(s',_) -> (s',1)) ()
        = snd $ case undefined () of ~(s',_) -> (s',1)
        = snd $ (undefined,1)
        = 1
```

these are not the same.  One option would be to define a function an extra class, like

```
class IsStrictness t where
   bindState :: State t s a -> (a -> State t s b) -> State t s b
```

and then then define

```
instance IsStrictness t => Monad (State t s) where
   return = returnState
   (>>=) = bindState
```

and instead of defining `bindState` as part of `IsStrictness`, you can use a singleton

```
data SingStrictness (t :: Strictness) where
   SingStrict :: SingStrictness Strict
   SingLazy   :: SingStrictness Lazy

class IsStrictness t where
   singStrictness :: SingStrictness t

bindState :: IsStrictness t => State t s a -> (a -> State t s b) -> State t s b
bindState ma' amb' = go singStrictness ma' amb' where
  go :: SingStrictness t -> State t s a -> (a -> State t s b) -> State t s b
  go SingStrict ma amb = ...
  go SingLazy ma amb = ...
```

which can be enhanced even further using the singelton infrastructures from GHC 7.6 instead of the custom class and singleton type.  You will end up with

```
instance SingI t => Monad (State t s)
```

which is really not so scary.  Get used to having lots of `SingI _` in your constraint sets.  This is how it is going to work for at least a while, and isn't that ugly.

As to why `State t [Bool]` is not deducible from `State t s`: the problem is that `State t s` is in your top level context, which means that `s` is quantified at the outermost level.  You are defining a function which says "for any t and s such that Monad (State t s) I will give you ...".   But, this doesn't say "for any t such that Monad (State t [Bool]) I will give you ...".  Sadly, these universally quantified constraints are not so easy in Haskell.

Comment: I'm content for `example` to react as it does at the moment, with an ambiguous type error – recognising that however that ambiguity is resolved, a `Monad` instance arises.

Comment: It seems like a type variable `t :: Strictness` can hold values `Strict`, `Lazy`, and sort-of-neither. I see your point about `State t s`, though, thanks. Seems like there ought to be a way to express the universal constraint.